# Can cherrypy serve two almost identical websites from the same project?

Tags: cherrypy

I'm aware that a single cherrpy instance can use the VirtualHost to handle multiple domains simultaneously.  I'm more specifically interested in having one project for two almost identical websites so i can cut out most of the repetitive dev and maintenance work.  Each website is targeting different industry terms and keywords.

I've been experimenting with cherrypy for a little while and like what I see so far but knowing it's possible would be another argument for switching.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; just have two different config files, and either make two `run.py` scripts, or pass different config to `cherryd`. You can add extra config for your own application needs and refer to it as described at http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/concepts/config.html#application-config